# Update option hook not firing

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-options

I've added an options page using this:

```
add_options_page(
    $title,
    $title,
    'read',
    'wp-video-reviews-licenses',
    array($this, 'render_licenses_menu')
);
```

Then in the callback:

```
public function render_licenses_menu()
{
    $title = sprintf(__('%s License', $this->text_domain), $this->product_name);
    $settings_group_id = $this->product_id . '-license-settings-group';

?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form action='options.php' method='post'>

            <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

            <?php
            settings_fields($settings_group_id);
            do_settings_sections($settings_group_id);
            submit_button();
            ?>

        </form>
    </div>
<?php

    //add_action('updated_option_wp-video-reviews-license-settings', array($this, 'register_license'), 10, 3);
    add_action('update_option', array($this, 'register_license'), 10, 3);
}
```

The problem is that when I submit the page for update, the hook "register_license" isn't called. But the field is correctly updated:

[image]

Why the hook isn't called?

Comment: Is this a question about https://github.com/jarkkolaine/wp-license-manager-client? Have you raised an issue asking about this there? If you are using it then you should include details of where and how you are using it. Also you don't need to modify the class to add your filter, and doing so prevents you getting updated versions of the class as you then have to manually modify it

Comment: @TomJNowell But this is not just a class problem. I tried to add `$this->loader->add_action('updated_option', $plugin_admin, 'test');` within `define_admin_hooks` function, and then I did: `function test($h, $c, $p)
 {
  var_dump(true);
  die();
 }`, but when I click on the submit button nothing happen.

Comment: I see you still haven't added the requested information to your question. Where, how, and when you use that class matters too, it's not enough to share the code for the class itself with us. It could be that what you're doing is in the wrong place, use the `Edit` link to modify your question to include the missing information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're registering your hook *inside* the function that is rendering the form. When the form is submitted, the `update_option` action has already run before it gets to displaying the form. Move it outside the function. As it appears you're using a class, adding the action to the `__construct` method might be a good idea.

Comment: I moved in the `__constructor` at the top of everything and same problem, function not called

Comment: check here: https://pastebin.com/ZVpZKPzM

Comment: can you add that code to your original question rather than a 3rd party service? And can you include information about how the `Wp_License_Manager_Client` is created/used not just its definition? As well as where the code is located? Cameron Jones is right but that doesn't mean there aren't additional steps they weren't aware you needed, and seeing the class helps but isn't quite enough